# What are the characteristics for a good report generation software for reporting and tracking software benchmarking results?

Tags: performance, report-generation, reporting, information-presentation

This is an offshoot question from this [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74697/can-software-performance-monitoring-profiling-be-automated-to-a-high-degree-as-i/74707#74707) to a previous [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/74697/620), where http://speed.pypy.org is highlighted as an example having a good presentation.

(However, it appears to me that the project doesn't separate the components of execution/tracking/report-generation/web-service, which makes it harder for other people to adopt.)

I am interested in both the functional and the UI requirements of such software. I hope to be able to choose an existing one based on the criteria so that I can use it in my project.

Right now, the only thing I can think of is that the Execution UI should be similar to a Unit Testing harness, but the Reporting UI should be totally different from the xUnit family of software. Webpages seem to be a better way to navigate through the results.

And, along with some minor ideas:

- There should be a tracking component to track performance changes at all levels
- However, the presentation layer should highlight only "relevant" performance changes, that is, performance drops in important areas that are serious enough to require developers' attention.

I am also interested in whether any of the advices from [Edward Tufte](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/index) can be applied here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [this so question about (macro-)benchmarking tools for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146207/what-is-the-best-macro-benchmarking-tool-framework-to-measure-a-single-threaded) interesting (even if you use a different language):

1. for runtime measurements, there are a lot of technical aspects to consider, mainly optimizations;
2. for runtime measurements, the statistics are very important, but very few tools implement them;
3. there are a lot of monitoring tools that offer a unit testing or logging like harness, and a standardized reporting interface (JMX) - just like you thought of;
4. Point 2 and 3 are somewhat contradictory: the execution has to know about the reporting to do the statistics right, i.e. to be able to decide how often some code should be executed and measured to get a high enough statistical confidence;
5. a good tool that is pretty language independent is Auto-pilot.